# Feign client always null when being added through a library, how can I fix it?

Tags: java, spring, feign

I'have lately working with feign on a project where I decided will package it and ship it as a library so it will be easier to use. All things worked fine but at the part where I invoke the feign client it just returns a NPE.

I am wondering if Im missing a configuration, or this is because the fact its a library? or how it is included in the project?

Basically I have something like this (in the library):

On a LibraryConfiguration.java

```
//some more beans
@Bean
public ClientService clientService(){
    return new ClientService();
}
```

at ClientService I have

```
 @Autowired
  private MyClient myClient;

  ClientService(){
   myClient.myResource();
  }
```

At MyClient:

```
@FeignClient(name = "auth", url = "${my-url}", configuration = MyClient.Configuration.class)
public interface MyClient {


  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/my-resource", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  String getResource(Map<String, ?> formParams);

  class Configuration {

    @Bean
    Encoder feignFormEncoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> converters) {
      return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(converters));
    }
  }
}
```

So it was all packaged and shipped.

At my app I have:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(LibraryConfiguration.class)
@EnableFeignClients()
@Configuration
@ImportAutoConfiguration(FeignAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyApiApplication {
....
}
```

I added the library like this (Im using gradle)

```
compile 'com.my-library:version'
```

Any idea of what could be missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the package level of the feign client is below the package level of the Main class(MyApiApplication).